# Reusable Service Class's methods to handle Multi-Level Cloning and related Operation which can be called from Trigger/WebService/Controller

Tags: apex, design-patterns

We have a SurveyApp where we deal with following objects:

1) Assessment

2) Section (Lookup to Assessment)

3) Question (Lookup to Section)

4) AnswerOption (Lookup to Question)

Inorder to handle each object business action, we have respective Service class in place.
Since most of object actions are from the AssessmentBuilder VF page, object specify actions are called one by one only. 
So the Service Class were not bulkified based on collection inputs.(MY FIRST MISTAKE)

In a nutshell,

**SectionService:**

```
class SectionService {
    //moves section(up/down) within the section
    public static List<Section__c> move(sectionId,direction,position) {}

    //move to new assessement/within assessment
    public static List<Section__c> moveToAssessment(sectionId,toAssessmentId) {}

    //copy with related childs to new assessment
    public static List<Section__c> copySectionToAssessment(sectionId,toAssessmentId) {}

    ...
}
```

**QuestionService:**

```
class QuestionService {
    //moves question(up/down) within the section
    public static List<Question__c> move(questionId,direction,position) {}

    //move to new section/within section
    public static List<Question__c> moveToSection(questionId,toSectionId) {}

    //copy question with related childs to new section
    public static List<Question__c> copyToSection(questionId,toSectionId) {}

    ...
}
```

Each Object's cloning operation has its own business rules/conditions which needs to implemented.
Everything was fine, until a new change was introduced which involves deeplcloning(multi-level) of Assessment records.

**AssessmentService:**

```
class AssessmentService {

    public static void deepClone(Set<Id> assessmentIdsToClone) {
        //insert cloned assessment
        //call SectionService method to do respective Section's cloning method
        //which inturn would call QuestionService's cloning method
        //which inturn would call AnswerOption's cloning method
    }
}
```

Also this cloning process can be invoked from multiple places. Like wise I anticipate it might happen for other objects as well.
So to accomodate bulkification, I need to use pass around list of Sections,Questions and AnswerOption's around, but my not sure if the methods would be reuseable from multiple sources.

Some of my colleagues say using redefined data structure(wrapper class structure) might help, something like:

```
class AssessmentWrapper {
    Assessment__c existingRecord,clonedRecord;
    List<SectionWrapper> sections;
} 

class SectionWrapper {
    Section__c existingRecord,clonedRecord;
    List<QuestionWrapper> questions;
}
...
```

Honestly I don't entirely get the wrapper class way of solving the problem.

My question here is, how can I efficiently redesign the Service classes so that I handle bulk cloning,moving,copying operations on object also reuse methods for ApexTriggers/WebServices/VF Controllers.

Comment: Upvoted because this appears applicable to a wide audience and just a good question. Unfortunately it may also be two broad. Double edge word so to speak. I hope you do get a decent answer as I think it would be helpful to many....

Comment: Thanks @Eric. I agree it might be broad as well but I believe many would have faced such problems and might have come up with good pattern to address it. If you any thought please do share it, it might be help others and ofcourse myself as well :-)

Comment: I have this dream also. My use case is pretty similar - I have a bunch of gateway classes that in my opinion are too complex. What I really want is to have the gateways be primarily driven by metadata settings - how to create multi level nested objects how to handle saves and queries from a controller or a trigger or even a batch process. I'm guessing Andrew Fawcett's Unit of Work pattern is the closest thing to this, but it seems like a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 4):

Wrappers encapsulate data. For example, consider this case where you don't use a wrapper at all, assuming we want bulkified processing of some hypothetical four-layer data:

```
Integer assessmentIndex, sectionIndex, questionIndex, answerOptionIndex;
for(assessmentIndex = 0; assessmentIndex < assessments.size(); assessmentIndex++) {
  for(sectionIndex = 0; sectionIndex < sections[assessmentIndex].size(); sectionIndex++) {
    for(questionIndex = 0; questionIndex < questions[assessmentIndex][sectionIndex].size(); questionIndex++) {
      for(answerOptionIndex = 0; answerOptionIndex < answeroptions[assessmentIndex][sectionIndex][questionIndex].size(); answerOptionIndex++) {
```

I had to pull the variable declarations on to their own lines to try and shorten the lines, and the code still flows off the edge of the screen; nothing short of using nonsense index variables would help here.

This is also CPU hungry, so users will have to wait longer. It's also potentially buggy, because we might run into ListException or NullPointerException a bit easier, since we're having to manually parse all of our data. It's not pretty.

Contrast this to a fully wrapped version:

```
for(AssessmentWrapper assessment: assessments) {
  for(SectionWrapper section: assessment.sections) {
    for(QuestionWrapper question: section.questions) {
      for(AnswerOptionWrapper answeroption: question.answeroptions) {
```

It's also a lot easier to pass data between methods as parameters, and since wrappers are references, we can also get rid of most of the reason why we're using return parameters (just make sure you document methods which are mutators; those that will alter the contents of the parameter). Also, since we now have wrappers, we can more easily assure ourselves that we're not going to hit ListException, and properly written wrapper classes should also be immune to NullPointerException.

But, even so, it's probably not enough. After all, what we basically have now is some basic rearrangement of storage. You could actually make the wrappers the Service Layer directly, writing things like:

```
public class Assessment {
  public static Assessment[] load(Id[] recordIds) { /* snip */ }

  public void add(Section newSection) { /* snip */ }
  public void remove(Section oldSection) { /* snip */ }
  public void moveBefore(Section source, Section target) { /* snip */ }
  public void moveAfter(Section source, Section target) { /* snip */ }
  public void moveDown(Section source) { /* snip */ }
  public void moveUp(Section source) { /* snip */ }
  // ...
}
public class Section {
  public void add(Question newQuestion) { /* snip */ }
  public void remove(Question oldQuestion) { /* snip */ }
  // ...
}
```

As a service layer, it really gives you a lot of control over how your logic is implemented; each method can implement its own business logic, and each layer really only communicates up or down one layer at a time, so code paths are more predictable. You could even enable chaining to create Builders, allowing you to write more concise code:

```
Assessment a = new Assessment();
a.add(new Section('Section'))
 .add(new Question('Foo'))
 .add(new AnswerOption('Bar'));
```

### tl;dr

Wrapper classes generally reduce the amount of code you need to write in classes/triggers/etc that call them, as well as encapsulating the data so they're easier to handle. Evolving wrapper classes into full Service Layer/Data Access Object (DAO) can provide even better benefits by standardizing queries, methods for manipulating data, etc.

Comment: Thank you sharing your insight. I like the way how wrapper class can also act as service layer. But how can we efficiently bulkify the methods ?  So that they can be invoked from multiple places (which might need Translator class which converts Wrapper to  respective sObject and vice-verse). For example if you take deep-level cloning on Assessment and related Childs, how can I properly implement it with Wrapper acting as Service Layer come DAO?